# Azure Tenant Admin cant read admin outlook with MS Graph / App Permission

Tags: c#, azure, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I want to create an app that can read any inbox in the Azure Tenant, here is some infos.

- My account used to register with Azure should be accessible with the app.
- My Outlook account == Azure Tenant Admin Account
- My Outlook account is an Office 365 - Personnal account.

I've created an App in Azure with the Ms Graph Application Permissions

- Mail.Read
- User.Read.All

The Admin consent has been granted.

I've tried to list the users in the tenant with this code below and it work.

It show my account in the list.

Then i try to access the mail folder of this account and it fail and i doesn't really know where to look at to resolve my issue.

i've added in comment some info about the throw result or hints

```
var scopes = new List<string> { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var clientCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(Secrets.TenantId, Secrets.ClientId, Secrets.ClientSecret);
var graph = new GraphServiceClient(clientCredential, scopes);

try
{
    var users = await graph.Users.GetAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(users.Value.Count); // => 1

    // UserId == Azure User Object Id
    // var mailbox = await graph.Users[Secrets.UserId].MailFolders.GetAsync(); // => ResourceNotFound

    // UserEmail == My Outlook Account that created the Azure Tenant so the Admin of the Tenant
    // var mailbox = await graph.Users[Secrets.UserEmail].MailFolders.GetAsync(); // => ErrorInvalidUser

    // UserPrincipalName = {alias}@{my-outlook-account}.onmicrosoft.com
    // var mailbox = await graph.Users[Secrets.UserPrincipalName].MailFolders.GetAsync(); // => ResourceNotFound

    // UserIssuer = {my-outlook-account}.onmicrosoft.com
    // var mailbox = await graph.Users[Secrets.UserIssuer].MailFolders.GetAsync(); // => ResourceNotFound

    if (users != null && users.Value != null && users.Value.Any())
    {
        var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(users.Value, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
        Console.WriteLine(json); // Show my user

        foreach (var user in users.Value)
        {
            var mailfolders = user.MailFolders.ToList(); // Throw because => MailFolders is null
            Console.WriteLine(mailfolders.Count);
        }
    }

}
catch (ODataError error)
{
    Console.WriteLine(error.Error.Code);
    Console.WriteLine(error.Error.Message);
    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The query to fetch the mail folder:

```
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(requestAdapter);

var result = await graphClient.Me.MailFolders["{mailFolder-id}"].GetAsync();
```

The permissions required for this query are:

[image]

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/mailfolder-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-1-get-a-mail-folder

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the way to query when you want delegated privilege your are right. That's why you use the  Me in the query.

In my case, it's the app that need to connect on behalf the user. 

Here is the case i try to implement https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service  but it's returning me "Resource Not Found" when my users is existing in the return of Users query.